# How to calculate consumer lag in Azure EventHub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have a C# .net 7 application where I publish events to an Azure EventHub on one side, and consume it on the other side using an Azure Function with the EventHubTrigger attribute.
I am using the following packages:

- `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs 5.7.5`
- `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.EventHubs 5.1.0`

```
[Function("HandleEventHubMessage")]
public async Task Run(
    [EventHubTrigger("<my-eventhub>", Connection = "<MyEventHubConnection>", ConsumerGroup = "<my-consumer-group>")] string[] messages, 
    FunctionContext context)
{
    ...
}
```

What I would like to do is to calculate the consumer lag between the received event position in the stream and the last sequence number for the current consumer group.

How can I retrieve these two information?

I tried using the `BlobCheckpointStore` to retrieve the `LastEnqueuedSequenceNumber` on each partition for my consumer group, but associated files in the azure storage stays empty. And for the received event, I have no clue on how to retrieve its position.

Comment: Checkpoint and ownership information are stored as metadata properties on the blob, not as part of blob content.   It is expected that the blob is empty.   The approach described by Jrdesc is what we'd recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that there is an Azure Monitor diagnostic available for Premium SKU and above that checks for consumer lag, [see this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/monitor-event-hubs-reference#application-metrics-logs)

But you can also calculate the lag programmatically by using [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.primitives.eventprocessor-1.readlastenqueuedeventproperties?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-eventhubs-primitives-eventprocessor-1-readlastenqueuedeventproperties(system-string)), then you compare the current event sequence that you are processing for a particular partition with the last enqueued one.

One more alternative is to use the [PartitionProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.partitionproperties?view=azure-dotnet) class which can also give you the last enqueued sequence on a per partition basis.